# Aggregate produces different row count when aggregated by same columns?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a simple yet puzzling question regarding aggregating my data on various columns. Suppose I have the following data set (called user_set) with about 6000 observations:

```
 user_id    number_of_hits    usd_amount
1  'Blah_1'      47             21.00
2  'Blah_17'     21            150.00
3  'acbd1'       17            300.00
4  'user27'      9               7.00
5  'foobar'      2              12.00
.
.
.
```

When I aggregate number_of_hits by user_id via the following code:

```
user_hits = aggregate(cbind(number_of_hits) ~ user_id, data=user_set, FUN=sum)
```

I get a frame returned to me with 5033 rows and 2 columns

Yet, when I aggregate usd_amount by user_id via the following code:

```
user_usd = aggregate(cbind(usd_amount) ~ user_id, data=user_set, FUN=sum)
```

I get a frame returned to me with 4749 rows and 2 columns.

THIS is what really puzzles me. Since I am aggregating different numerical columns by the exact same non-numerical column (i.e. user_id) shouldn't both results give me data frames with an equal number of rows? Any pointers on why this could be possible would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without the full data set. My guess is that you have `NA` values in `usd_amount` and `aggregate` will remove those rows completely, thus removing some of the user IDs.

Comment: You don't need `cbind`, just `aggregate(number_of_hits ~ user_id, data=user_set, FUN=sum)` should work just as well. Moreover, you may want to extend the aggregation to `aggregate(number_of_hits ~ user_id, user_set, sum, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Could it be that there are some non-numeric values or NAs for number_of_hits or usd_amount? You can try the `data.table` approach for aggregating instead: `dt <- as.data.table(your_data_frame)`. Then aggregate as `dt[, sum(usd_amount), by = user_id]`

Comment: @LyzandeR @Gautam - you two are both correct. I assumed I had a full dataset, but turns out yes, usd_amount actually did have few `NA` values.

Comment: @Jaap and yes you're right, thank you. I'll be sure to clean that up in my code